# Why are my databound TreeView items blank?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, treeview

I have the following markup in a `ServiceTree` control, which should present a `TreeView` of services in a `ServiceGroup`:

```
<Grid>
    <TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Services}" DataContext="{Binding}">
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" DataType="{x:Type businessService:BusinessService}">
                <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
    </TreeView>
</Grid>
```

In the top level binding, `Services` is the collection of services that belongs to a `ServiceGroup`.

In the main window, I use the following data binding to create an `OdcExpander` from the [Odyssey](http://odyssey.codeplex.com/) project:

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate DataType="groups:ServiceGroup">
        <odc:OdcExpander Header="{Binding UIMetadata.MenuText}"  HeaderBackground="{Binding UIMetadata.MenuTabBackColor}">                            
            <XTime900Shell:ServiceTree />                            
        </odc:OdcExpander>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

This works. I get one expander correctly bound to each `ServiceGroup`, but on the groups with services, i.e. the "Employees" group, there is a space where the treeview should be, proportional in height to the number of services it should show, so it is binding to the `Services` collection property, and creating an item for each service, but not displaying anything for the service 'Name` property, which I know is correctly populated.

Comment: are you getting any binding errros in output window?

Answer (score 1):

I think the error is that your are using a TreeViewItem, you should not. If you are creating a data template you can show any visual item, for instance a text block. The tree view item will be the container item, that you will show as a text box (for instace). you should do like this:

```
<TreeView.ItemTemplate>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Children}" DataType="{x:Type businessService:BusinessService}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

Hope works...

Comment: It works just as is in other scenarios though, and, still doesn't work in this one when I rather use a `TextBlock`.

Comment: Turns out `Children` was a `Dictionary`, not a list. Fixed that and everything works.